# Add click event listener to a jQuery inline datepicker

Tags: jquery

I was able to make an inline jQuery datepicker style calendar so that when there are events happening on a certain day, it will be highlighted.

Now the problem is, I want to add a event listener to that specific highlighted dates, so that when user clicks on that date, the page will return all events happening on that day.

Right now I am using the following method as a workaround

```
$j('#datePicker').click(function(){
  var selectedDate = $j('#datePicker').datepicker("getDate");
  //function to retrieve all events on selectedDate;        
});
```

but it has drawbacks,

1. When I click on any part of the calendar, the event is fired;
2. It doesn't filter the un-highlighted dates;

What is the proper way to add click event listener to a specific date? I know for some advanced jQuery coders it is pretty basic. Sorry if someone has already asked the question, I looked it up in the API but couldn't find anything.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: I bet you can bind the handler to the `change` event instead. You probably have to do the filtering inside the handler.